# Laravel 4 RESTful API - resource controller - deeper request hierarchy

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building my frontend part of the API system.
Using default [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)'s by Laravel you can achieve this type of requests:

> http://superapi.com/v1/soccer/10

Which will call the:
/app/controllers/SoccerController.php @ show($id) method

I need at least one more level of depth, to be able to do it like this:

> http://superapi.com/v1/soccer/player/10

So it will resolve to:

/app/controllers/SoccerController.php @ show() method having both, "player" and "10" arguments.

```
public function show($model)
{
    return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Test ' . $model));
}
```

Laravel passes only 1 parameter to method, and I cannot find anything about how to pass more.

I'm doing this basically because my 1 controller is responsible for talking to a few Models, not just one. Either SoccerPlayer or SoccerTeam or SoccerSchedule, it all should be nicely put under 
`/v1/<controller>/<type>/<id>`

Advices?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want more control over your routes I advice you to explicitly define the routes rather than using the `resource controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the best of both worlds anyway, by placing a custom route before the resource route:

```
Route::get('soccer', 'SoccerController@show');
Route::resource('soccer', 'SoccerController', array('except' => array('show')));
```

Now the `show()` method will be **escluded from the resource controller** control (thus calling `soccer/10` or `soccer/player` will lead to a `NotFoundHttpException`), and placed into your custom route.
You'll need to edit the `show()` method to accept the second parameter though:

```
public function show($type, $id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [route prefixing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'soccer'), function()
{

    Route::resource('player', 'PlayerController');

});
```

then, you can put all soccer relavant controllers in the same namespace (and same folder) like `Soccer`. in this case, change the above route to

```
Route::resource('player', 'Soccer\PlayerController');
```